# Не могу понять причину ошибки IndexError: list assignment index out of range Python. Как можно это исправить?

Tags: python, массивы

https://pastebin.com/VeTyWYbA

```
a = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(0,7):
    a.append(int(input()))
ms = 0
maxs = 0
for i in range(1,n-7):
    a[8] = int(input())
    if a[1]>ms:
        ms=a[1]
    if ms+a[8] > maxs:
        maxs = ms+a[8]
    for j in range(1,7):
        a[j] = a[j+1]
print(maxs)
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> a[8] = int(input()) IndexError: list assignment index out of range
> ```

И сама задача, по которой я писала

На вход программы подаются результаты измерений, выполняемых прибором с интервалом 1 минуту. Требуется найти наибольшую сумму двух результатов измерений, выполненных с интервалом не менее, чем в 7 минут.
Описание выходных данных

Программа должна вывести одно число наибольшую сумму двух результатов измерений, выполненных с интервалом не менее, чем в 7 минут.
Пример входных данных:
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Пример выходных данных для приведённого выше примера входных данных:
13

Answer (score 0):

Выход за пределы списка `a`. У вас он имеет длину 7, а вы просите элемент по индексу >6.